# Xamarin StartTimer subtract seconds from TimeSpan don't work

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am programming a countdown timer with Xamarin Forms using the StartTimer method of Device class. The problem is that the selected time is not reduced by seconds but remains as originally selected. I don't know where the problem is. Thanks for the help.

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private int minutes = 0;
    private int hours = 0;
    private TimeSpan restTime = TimeSpan.Zero;

    public MainPage()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        StartCountdown(hours, minutes);
    }


    public void StartCountdown(int hours, int min)
    {
        var M = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(min);

        var H = TimeSpan.FromHours(hours);

        restTime = H.Add(M);

        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
        {
            //Here should subtract from variable restTime one second every second 
            restTime.Add(new TimeSpan(0,0,-1));

            if (restTime == TimeSpan.Zero)
            {
                //Do something
                return false; 
            }
            else
            {

                return true; 
            }

        });

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling `restTime.Add`, but not doing anything with the result, here:

```cs
restTime.Add(new TimeSpan(0,0,-1));
```

The `Add` method doesn't change the existing `TimeSpan` - it returns a new one. Instead, you want:

```cs
restTime = restTime.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, -1));
```

Or more readably IMO:

```cs
restTime -= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
```

(I'd also use `restTime = new TimeSpan(hours, min, 0);` to start with, probably. Or maybe `restTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(hours) + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(min);`.)

You might want to have a field for one second:

```cs
private static readonly TimeSpan OneSecond = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

...
restTime -= OneSecond;
```

Comment: @Yves If JonSkeet's reply help you, please remember to mark it as answer, it is beneficial to others who face the same problem.